# display text on a child window in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html page with a form

```
<form>
   test : <input type="text" id="mot">
   <button type="button" onclick="send()">Envoi</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="openNewWindow()">nouveau</button>
   <button type="button" onclick="refresh()">Refresh</button>
</form>
```

and another html page with a div

```
<div id=result></div>
```

I'm trying to display the text entered in the form to the child window with the div.
I create the new windows with the "openNewWindow" function. I can refresh that windows with the "refresh" function. But the send function does not work.

```
var childWindow = ""
var newTabUrl = "./display.html"


function send(){
  document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#mot").value;
  childWindow.document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = document.querySelector("#mot").value;
}

function openNewWindow(){
  childWindow = window.open(newTabUrl,"display");
}

function refresh(){
  childWindow.location.href=newTabUrl;
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: These functions are operating independently - there is no guarantee that the `childWindow` has been instantiated when the `Envoi` button is clicked.

Comment: childWindow is delcared outside of the different function and should be the same object for all. No?
I assume it works like that as the refresh function is working

Comment: Indeed that is true - however the buttons would need to be clicked in particular order

Comment: First "nouveau" to trigger "openNewWindow" which will open the child window and store it in "childWindow" and then "Envoi" to trigger "send" that should update "result". But the second does not work

Comment: I would suggest that perhaps a better method of sending data between parent/child windows exists - for example, the [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel/BroadcastChannel) would be ideal for this imo

Comment: I found an example with broadxastChannel. I copied it and it works. Now I have to understand it.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mentioned in a comment that the [BroadcastChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BroadcastChannel/BroadcastChannel) API might be a perfect candidate for your needs so put together a quick demo to illustrate how it might be used. For the demo there are essentially 3 files - 2 html and 1 javascript.
I appreciate that you have found an example but I had put together a demo so thought I should share it.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>MOT-Form</title>
        <script src='app.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    
        <form method='post' name='app'>
            <label>Test : <input type='text' name='mot' /></label>
            <button type='button' data-task='open' title='Open new window'>Nouveau</button>
            <button type='button' data-task='send' title='Send data to child window'>Envoi</button>
            <button type='button' data-task='refresh' title='Refresh child window'>Refresh</button>
            <button type='button' data-task='close' title='Close the child window'>Close</button>
        </form>
        
        <div id='result'></div>
        
        <script>
            (function(){
                /*
                    Establish base options for the app
                    and create a new BroadcastChannel
                    - event listeners are bound when the
                    channel has been created and have 
                    access to the `channel` object 
                    returned/resolved by the `createchannel`
                    method.
                    
                    BroadcastChannel is bi-directional but
                    we only need in a single direction.
                */
                createchannel( _CHANNELNAME )
                    .then( channel=>{
                        let win=false;
                        
                        const w=800;
                        const h=600;
                        
                        const options={
                            menubar:0,
                            location:0,
                            resizable:0,
                            scrollbars:0,
                            status:0,
                            width:w,
                            height:h,
                            left:( ( screen.availWidth - w ) / 2 ),
                            top:( ( screen.availHeight - h ) / 2 )
                        };
                        const mot=document.forms.app.mot;
                        const result=document.getElementById('result');
                        const bttns=document.forms.app.querySelectorAll('button[data-task]');
                        
                        
                        
                        bttns.forEach( bttn => bttn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                            try{
                                switch( this.dataset.task ){
                                    case 'send':
                                        result.textContent=mot.value;
                                        return sendmessage( channel, 'message', mot.value );
                                    case 'open':
                                        win=openwindow( 'popup.html', 'popup', options );
                                    break;
                                    case 'refresh':
                                        mot.value='';
                                        result.textContent='';
                                        
                                        return sendmessage( channel, 'refresh', null );
                                    case 'close':
                                        if( win )win.close();
                                    break;
                                }
                            }catch(err){
                                console.log(err.message)
                            }
                        }))                         
                    })
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>MOT-Popup</title>
        <script src='app.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='result'></div>
        <script>
            (function(){
            
                const callback=(e)=>{
                    if( e.data.type=='refresh' )location.reload(true);
                    document.querySelector('div#result').textContent=e.data.payload;
                    console.info(e);
                };
                
                createchannel( _CHANNELNAME, callback )
                    .then( channel => {
                        console.log( channel )
                    });
            })();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**app.js**

```
const _CHANNELNAME='mot-app';

/*
    shorthand for node.querySelector(expr)
    
    e:expression
    n:parent node
*/
const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);


/*
    Using a Promise to chain the creation of the
    BroadcastChannel to other functionality.
    
    name: name of the BroadcastChannel to create/subscribe to
    callback: the function that is executed when a message is received
*/
const createchannel=function(name,callback){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
        let oChannel=new BroadcastChannel( name );
        
        if( callback ){
            oChannel.addEventListener('message',(e)=>{
                callback( e );
            });
            oChannel.addEventListener('messageerror',e=>{
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
        resolve( oChannel );
    })
};


/*
    utility to send formatted 
    message over BroadcastChannel
    
    c:channel
    t:type
    d:data
*/
const sendmessage=(c,t,d) => c && d!='' ? c.postMessage({'type':t,'payload':d}) : false;


/*
    utility to open a new window
    attributes supplied as an object
    
    u:url
    n:name
    a:attributes
*/
const openwindow=(u,n,a)=>window.open(u,n,Object.keys(a).map(k=>[k,a[k]].join('=')));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this, showing results on a blank page :)

```
var childWindow;
var newUrl = "about:blank";

function newWindow(){
   childWindow = window.open(newUrl, "_blank", "");
}
function showResults(){
   const div = document.createElement("div");
   div.style.color = "blue";
   childWindow.document.body.appendChild(div);
   div.innerHTML = "Result : "+document.querySelector("#mot").value;
}
function refreshWindow(){
   childWindow.location = childWindow.location;
   setTimeout(showResults, 100);
}
```

*tested on chrome console*