# Update image source form one html page to another

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a scoreboard in html that is controlled by another html page. I work with messages like proposed in the answer of my previous post ([display text on a child window in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68905459/display-text-on-a-child-window-in-javascript/68933561#68933561))
It is working really good and I can update text. Now I'm trying to change the source of an image.

main.js

```
const setFaute1 = (faute1) => {
    afffaute1.innerHTML = faute1;
    switch (faute1) {
        case 1:
            faute11.src = './images/FillFault.png';
            break;
        case 2:
            faute12.src = './images/FillFault.png';
            break;
        case 3:
            faute13.src = './images/FillFault.png';
            break;
        case 0:
            faute11.src = './images/EmptyFault.png';
            faute12.src = './images/EmptyFault.png';
            faute13.src = './images/EmptyFault.png';
            break;
    }
    bc.onmessage = (messageEvent) => {
        switch (messageEvent.data) {
            case 'update_mot':
                setMot(localStorage.getItem('mot'));
                break;
            case 'update_equipe1':
                setEquipe1(localStorage.getItem('equipe1'));
                break;
            case 'update_equipe2':
                setEquipe2(localStorage.getItem('equipe2'));
                break;
            case 'update_score1':
                setScore1(localStorage.getItem('score1'));
                break;
            case 'update_score2':
                setScore2(localStorage.getItem('score2'));
                break;
            case 'update_faute1':
                setFaute1(localStorage.getItem('faute1'));
                break;
            case 'update_faute2':
                setFaute2(localStorage.getItem('faute2'));
                break;
            default:
        }
    };
    btnfaute1.onclick = (e) => {
        var value = parseInt(afffaute1.innerHTML, 10);
        if (value < 3) {
            value++;
        } else {
            value = 0;
        }
        localStorage.setItem('faute1', value);
        afffaute1.innerHTML = value;
        setFaute1(value);
        bc.postMessage('update_faute1');
    };
};
```

It displays correctly on the page where the button is but not on the second page. The text field updates correctly.

I don't understand why. Can someone help me?

Full code : https://gitlab.com/roger.julien/tableau-affichage-impro/-/tree/fautes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The localstorage stores string. And my case was comparing integer. I just had to convert the string to an integer and it works.